# Cant find package BLT on Tcl Tk8.6

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am having a problem of getting BLT to work with Tcl/TK. I installed BLT library for TCL/TK but when i try running a tcl program to plot a graph, it keeps giving me an error saying "can't find package BLT". In my program I have already included:

```
package require BLT
```

I also appended the BLT part to my environmental variable on my windows operating system 32 bit but it still doesn't work.

Here is a little script that i wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

lappend auto_path "C:/Tcl/Tcl/lib"

package require BLT

#puts "Testing"
```

I need to plot an interactive graph. Please what do i need to do?

Comment: Do you know where you installed BLT to? I am sorry, but I don't have my Windows machine up at the moment.

Comment: @Donal, Yes I do know where I installed BLT. That is the path I specified in the lappend auto_path "C:/Tcl/Tcl/lib". I've been stocked up with it for the past few days and it's urgent. Please help!.

Comment: What is the contents of the `pkgIndex.tcl` in that directory? Is there a `pkgIndex.tcl` in one of the _immediate_ subdirectories of that directory that mentions BLT?

Comment: proc LoadBLT { version dir } {

    set prefix ""
    set suffix [info sharedlibextension]
    regsub {\.} $version {} version_no_dots

    # Determine whether to load the full BLT library or
    # the "lite" tcl-only version.
    
    if { [info commands tk] == "tk" } {
        set name ${prefix}BLT${version_no_dots}${suffix}
    } else {
        set name ${prefix}BLTlite${version_no_dots}${suffix}
    }
    
    global tcl_platform
    if { $tcl_platform(platform) == "unix" } {
 set library [file join $dir $name]

Comment: if { ![file exists $library] } {
     # Try the parent directory.
     set library [file join [file dirname $dir] $name]
 }
 if { ![file exists $library] } {
     # Default to the path generated at compilation.
     set library [file join "C:/Program Files/Tcl/lib" $name]
 }
    } else {
 set library $name
    }
    load $library BLT
}

set version "2.4"

package ifneeded BLT $version [list LoadBLT $version $dir]

# End of package index file

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. That's the content of the pkgIndex.tcl file.

Comment: If possible, I don't mind you connecting to my computer remotely and having a look at it if you have the time please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for additional details. Comments aren't the best place to put this, though. You should instead modify your original question to add additional information.